# Write If Statement Variable to New File

Tags: perl

I am trying to send a variable that is defined in an if statement `$abc` to a new file. The code seems correct but, I know that it is not working because the file is not being created.

**Data File Sample:**

```
bos,control,x1,x2,29AUG2016,y1,y2,76.4
bos,control,x2,x3,30AUG2016,y2,y3,78.9
bos,control,x3,x4,01SEP2016,y3,y4,72.5
bos,control,x4,x5,02SEP2016,y4,y5,80.5
```

**Perl Code:**

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings 'all';

use POSIX qw(strftime); #Pull in date

my $currdate = strftime( "%Y%m%d", localtime ); #Date in YYYYMMDD format
my $modded = strftime( "%d%b%Y", localtime ); #Date in DDMONYYYY format
my $newdate = uc $modded; #converts lowercase to uppercase

my $filename = '/home/.../.../text_file'; #Define full file path before opening

open(FILE, '<', $filename) or die "Uh, where's the file again?\n"; #Open file else give up and relay snarky error

while(<FILE>) #Open While Loop
{
  chomp;

  my @fields = split(',' , $_); #Identify columns

  my $site = $fields[0];
  my $var1 = $fields[1];
  my $var2 = $fields[4];
  my $var3 = $fields[7];

  my $abc = print "$var1,$var2,$var3\n" if ($var1 =~ "control" && $var2 =~ "$newdate");


  open my $abc, '>', '/home/.../.../newfile.txt';
  close $abc;

}

close FILE;
```

Comment: You have a couple of very strange things going on in there. I believe your code does not do what you think it does at all. As for the correctness of the code, I do not see a syntax error in it. It will likely compile. But it's weird.

Comment: `print` returns `true` or `false` based on its success or failure. What are you trying to get in `$abc`? If that variable needs to contain `$var1,$var2,$var3\n` then you should omit the `print`, open the file to write to (possibly in append mode `>>` so you won't overwrite) and print to that filehandle.

Answer (score 4):

In your code you have a few odd things that are likely mistakes.

```
my $abc = print "$var1,$var2,$var3\n" if ($var1 =~ "c01" && $var2 =~ "$newdate");
```

- `print` will return success, which it does as `1`. So you will print out the string to STDOUT, and then assign `1` to a new lexical variable `$abc`. `$abc` is now `1`.
- All of that only happens if that condition is met. Don't do conditional assignments. The behavior for this is *undefined*. So if the condition is false, your `$abc` might be `undef`. Or something else. Who knows?

```
open my $abc, '>', '/home/.../.../newfile.txt';
close $abc;
```

- You are opening a new filehandle called `$abc`. The `my` will redeclare it. That's a warning that you would get if you had `use warnings` in your code. It also overwrites your old `$abc` with a new file handle object.
- You don't write anything to the file
- `...` are weird foldernames, but that's probably just obfuscation for your example

I think what you actually want to do is this:

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';

# ...

open my $fh, '<', $filename or die $!;
while ( my $line = <$fh> ) {
    chomp $line;

    my @fields = split( ',', $line );

    my $site = $fields[0];
    my $var1 = $fields[1];
    my $var2 = $fields[4];
    my $var3 = $fields[7];

    open my $fh_out, '>', '/home/.../.../newfile.txt';
    print $fh_out "$var1,$var2,$var3\n" if ( $var1 =~ "c01" && $var2 =~ "$newdate" );
    close $fh_out;
}
close $fh;
```

You don't need the `$abc` variable in between at all. You can just print to your new file handle `$fh_out` that's open for writing.

Note that you will overwrite the `newfile.txt` file every time you have a match in a line inside `$filename`.

Comment: Thank you very much for helping me out with my wonky code! I am currently getting the following output from the `print $fh_out` line :`GLOB(0x2643690)`, and still no new file.

Comment: The `GLOB()` is a filehandle reference. In my code above, note that there is **no comma** after the `print $fh_out`. That's because it tells `print` where to print to.

Comment: Any idea as to why I am still having a problem with `"$var1,$var2,$var3\n"` not being passed to a new file named `newfile.txt`?

Comment: @Aaaron without seeing updated code, I cannot answer that. You can edit your question and add the new code to the end with an explanation of what you updated and I'll take a look.

Comment: Updated the code for you. As for the code that you suggested, I have not changed any of it. I just copy/pasted and I am getting a new file but, it's empty (0 bytes).

Comment: @AaronPerry reread my answer. If you run the code that you have in the question now, then it's still valid. You are not writing anything into the file, and the other things are still wrong. Just go through my answer point by point, and if you don't understand parts of it, ask in a comment.

Comment: *"Don't do conditional assignments. If the condition is false, your `$abc` will be undef."*  There is nothing wrong with conditional assignments; the issue is with conditional *declarations*. [**perlsyn** says this](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsyn.html#Statement-Modifiers) *"The behaviour of a `my`, `state`, or `our` modified with a statement modifier conditional or loop construct (for example, `my $x if ...` ) is* **undefined**.*"*

Comment: @AaronPerry:  *"I am getting a new file but, it's empty (0 bytes)"* Maybe that's because none of the lines in your input contain `c01` in the second column? There are certainly no such lines in your sample data.

Answer (score 2):

Your current code:

1. Prints the string
2. Assigns the result of printing it to a variable
3. Immediately overwrites that variable with a file handle (assuming `open` succeeded)
4. Closes that file handle without using it

Your logic should look more like this:

```
if ( $var1 =~ "c01" && $var2 =~ "$newdate" ) {
    my $abc = "$var1,$var2,$var3\n"
    open (my $file, '>', '/home/.../.../newfile.txt') || die("Could not open file: " . $!);
    print $file $abc;
    close $file;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a number of problems with your code. In addition to what others have mentioned

- You create a new output file every time you find a matching input line. That will leave the file containing only the *last* printed string
- Your test checks whether the text in the second column contains `c01`, but all of the lines in your sample input have `control` in the second column, so nothing will be printed
- I'm guessing that you want to test for *string equality*, in which case you need `eq` instead of `=~` which does a regular expression pattern match

I think it should look something more like this

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';

use POSIX 'strftime';

my $currdate = uc strftime '%d%b%Y', localtime;

my ($input, $output) = qw/ data.txt newfile.txt /;

open my $fh,     '<', $input  or die qq{Unable to open "$input" for input: $!};
open my $out_fh, '>', $output or die qq{Unable to open "$output" for output: $!};

while ( <$fh> ) {
  chomp;

  my @fields = split /,/;
  my ($site, $var1, $var2, $var3) = @fields[0,1,4,7];

  next unless $var1 eq 'c01' and $var2 eq $currdate;

  print $out_fh "$var1,$var2,$var3\n";
}

close $out_fh or die $!;
```